# Set start and finish limits to read from file

Tags: c++, file, io, position

I need to read data from a txt file. Data I need starts in the some position in file and ends in the other position(not in the end). I know how to change start position (fin.seekg(startPos);), but how to set my finish position?
I have a limit numbers, say start read at 100 position from begin and stop in 30 from end.

Comment: If you know the finish position, then subtract the start position from it, and read no more than that many characters from the file. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fin.tellg like this:

```
fin.seekg(0, fin.end);
length = fin.tellg();
```

to count the total number of 'positions' in the file. Then go to the desired start position and get input until the number of positions minus 30. Complete sample:

```
int startPos = 100, length;
string input;
ifstream fin("file.txt");

fin.seekg(0, fin.end);
length = fin.tellg();
fin.seekg(startPos);

for (int i = startPos; i <= length - 30; i++) {
    getline(fin, input, '\n')
    //do something with 'input'
}

fin.close();
```

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!